# Get all albums by a specific band in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've created a few tables called `Formed, Track, Album, Band, Customers` in `MySQL` and I'm using `MySQL Workbench`. In the `Formed` table, I have the year a band was formed, country and city the band was formed, and the band members. In the `Track` table, I have the songs, the track count so how many songs are on an album, the title of the album, and the total track duration. In the `Album` table, I have the price, title, and genre. In the `Band` table, I have the record label, and in the `Customers` table, I have the name, phone number, email, and if they've paid.

However I want to try and create an SQL script that can get all the albums by a band. The only way that I've seen is by using

```
SELECT Albums,Band FROM Album;
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM Album;
```

But I'm not 100% sure if there's a better, more effective way of doing it.

**EDIT**

The code that I have is:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Formed;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Band;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Customers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

CREATE TABLE Formed(
    FormedID int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    YearFormed int, 
    CountryFormed varchar(50), 
    CityFormed varchar(50), 
    BandMembers varchar(400), 
    PRIMARY KEY(FormedID))
    ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Track (
    TrackID int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    AlbumID int,
    Songs varchar(200), 
    TrackNumber varchar(20), 
    Title varchar(30), 
    TrackDuration varchar(6), 
    PRIMARY KEY(TrackID)) 
    ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Album(
    AlbumID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TrackID int,
    BandID int,
    KEY(TrackID),
    KEY(BandID),
    Price int, 
    PublicationDate varchar(11), 
    Title varchar(30), 
    Genre varchar(36),
    PRIMARY KEY(AlbumID))
    ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Band(
    BandID int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    AlbumID int, 
    KEY(AlbumID),
    RecordLabel varchar(50), 
    PRIMARY KEY(BandID))
    ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Customers (
    CustomerID int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    CName varchar(20), 
    CPhone varchar(12), 
    CEmail varchar(50), 
    CPPaid varchar(50), 
    CPDate date, 
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID))
    ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE Track 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (AlbumID) REFERENCES Album(AlbumID)ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Album
ADD FOREIGN KEY (TrackID) REFERENCES Track(TrackID)ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Album
ADD FOREIGN KEY (BandID) REFERENCES Band(BandID)ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Band
ADD FOREIGN KEY (AlbumID) REFERENCES Album(AlbumID)ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: If you have a proper relational structure you can do this easily. If not it's anyone's guess. What schema are using for these?

Comment: @tadman the schema? I'm using a schema called `Tables`

Comment: What is `Formed`? .A `Band ` is formed only once. Therefore `Formed` should be a column in `Band`. `BandMembers` should be a separate table.  Ie your schema is garbage.

Comment: @davidstrachan Why say that a schema is garbage? Is there any need to add that into the comment?

Comment: @smitthy you are using a terrible db structure that goes against any normal logic

Comment: @LelioFaieta Okay, I'll keep that it mind and try and edit it round

Comment: Don't forget to add indexes on things like `BandID` when referenced in other tables to make your queries perform efficiently.

Comment: `Formed` is not an **entity**, it is an is an **attribute** of `Band`. If you submit this schema your lecturer will use stronger words than I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join, so for instance if you wanted the title for a particular band:

```
Select a.Title from Album a
Inner Join Band b on a.BandID = b.BandID
Where a.BandID = X
```

Comment: So I could use that to display all the albums from one band? Because when I run it, I get `Error code: 1052. Column 'BandID' in on clause is ambiguous`

Comment: Edited my answer.  Since you have a join with BandID in both tables, my previous example did not tell MySQL which table I wanted BandID from.  I am assuming it's the Album table in the above example.  And 'X' in my example would be the Band ID you want the title(s) from.